# Exp meter in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have this function. It fills my exp meter well, but when the exp is greater than the remaining exp to the next level it just shrinks down to zero. What I want is for the meter to fill up to 100% and THEN continue to fill the amount that is left from the exp earned on the next level.
I hope I'm being clear here. Otherwise tell me and I will try and explain it better.

What is this function missing?

```
//These are my variables
var currentXP = 0;
var level = 1;
var maxXP = 250;

//This is my function
function Grow() {
    if(currentXP <= maxXP){
            $('#active_meter').animate({height:currentXP + "px"}, 500);
        }else{
            currentXP = maxXP - currentXP;
            level++;
            console.log("Level: " + level);
            $('#active_meter').animate({height:currentXP + "px"}, 500);
            document.getElementById("level").innerHTML = level;
    }
  }
```

Comment: You have the subtraction backwards. It should be `currentXP - maxXP`

Comment: @Barmar Even if I change that it functions the same. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: Then I'm not really sure what you're trying to do. Can you make an executable stack snippet that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: If you do the subtraction correctly, then when `currentXP` goes to 260, it will increase the level and set `currentXP = 10`. Isn't that what's left on the next level?

Comment: @Barmar I want the animation to always fill the meter before resetting. Like in a game where you have an exp meter.

Comment: You'll need to do two animations in that case. First animate it to `maxXP`, then in the completion callback function animate it from 0 to the new `currentXP`.

Comment: I don't play many video games, I'm unfamiliar with that style of displaying the experience meter.

Comment: @Barmar I understand what you just described. Seems like a plan. But I have no idea how to implement it. Could you provide a code snippet of how it could be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the experience goes over the max, animate it up to the max and set `currentXP to the amount left over in the new level. In the completion function for that animation, set the height down to`0` and animate it up to the new exp level.

```
//These are my variables
var currentXP = 0;
var level = 1;
var maxXP = 250;

//This is my function
function Grow() {
  if (currentXP <= maxXP) {
    $('#active_meter').animate({
      height: currentXP + "px"
    }, 500);
  } else {
    currentXP = currentXP - maxXP;
    level++;
    console.log("Level: " + level);
    $('#active_meter').animate({
      height: maxXP + "px"
    }, 500, function() {
      $('#active_meter').css('height', '0px').animate({
        height: currentXP + "px"
      }, 500);
    });
    document.getElementById("level").innerHTML = level;
  }
}
```